# why "abstract method 'onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup, int)' cannot be accessed directly on handling item click recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

Error Message
[this error because i m using firebase dependency newest version 16.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVXWS.png)
please anyone can help me ?

Comment: You need to share your code as **Text** not as image

Comment: There are lot of RecyclerView example, You should search before asking.

Comment: because the method is abstract, you can't call abstract methods. Why? - Check the Java basics for the answer

Answer (score 0):

When you're implementing an abstract method you can't directly call it. it's an empty template - you have to fill it by yourself! That's basic Java/OOP basics

Read up on RecyclerView.Adapter basic implementations to continue forward.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview